# How to change str object to datetime.time in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

First adding the code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date, time

with open('T2.csv') as readcsvfile:
    readcsv=csv.reader(readcsvfile)
    header=next(readcsv)

    data=[]
    for row in readcsv:
        # if-else construct to read both empty & time string       
        if row[0]==str():
            date=str()
        else:date=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%y%m%d')
        # stripping the 170101 part with str(ing)p(arse)time and
        # changing the style/format into '%Y/%m/%d' format with strftime.

        ID=str(row[5])

        if row[6]==str():
            O_all=str()
        else:O_all=datetime.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M')

        Combined_datetime=datetime.combine(date,O_all)
        data.append([Combined_datetime,ID])
  print(data)
```

Yields the error:

```
Combined_datetime=datetime.combine(date,O_all)
TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not str
```

But if I check the types, both "date" & "O_all" are 'datetime.datetime' objects. I guess I'm missing something or understood something wrongly. What could be the remedy to get a timetuple named as 'Combined_datetime'?

Comment: Make be because of `.strftime('%H:%M')` in `O_all=datetime.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: @amarnath When I remove `.strftime('%H:%M')` the error is change to `TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elsewhere. While reading my csv, I could read all the row with simple if-else construct (empty time was considered as empty string). But while combining the date & time with `datetime.combine(d,t)`, it could not handle the empty strings.
@amarnath Your suggestion for adding `.time()` helped though. I removed the rows with empty time this time. Actually it overrides the `TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not str` error in this way.
Here is the complete working code:

```
#Reading T2 & writing new csv

import csv
from datetime import datetime, date, time

with open('T2.csv') as readcsvfile:
    readcsv=csv.reader(readcsvfile)
    header=next(readcsv)

    data=[]
    for row in readcsv:
    #if-else construct to read both empty & time string       
        if row[6]!=str():
            d=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%y%m%d')
            t=datetime.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M').time()
        print(type(d))
    ##stripping the 170101 part with str(ing)p(arse)time and
    ##changing t from datetime.datetime to datetime.time with `.time()`
        print(type(t))
        ID=str(row[5])

        Combined_datetime = datetime.combine(d, t)
        data.append([Combined_datetime,ID])
        print(data)

with open('T2_w3.csv','w',newline='') as writecsvfile:
    writecsv=csv.writer(writecsvfile)
    writecsv.writerow(['Combined_datetime','ID'])

    for i in range(len(data)):
        ROW=data[i]
        CDT=ROW[0]
        ID=ROW[1]
        Final_list=[CDT,ID]
        writecsv.writerow(Final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update with this code

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date, time

with open('T2.csv') as readcsvfile:
    readcsv=csv.reader(readcsvfile)
    header=next(readcsv)

    data=[]
    Combined_datetime = 
    for row in readcsv:

        if len(row[0])<0:
            date=str()
        else:
            date=datetime.strptime(row[0],'%y%m%d')

        ID=str(row[5])

        if len(row[6])<0:
            O_all=str()
        else:
            O_all=datetime.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M').time()

        if date and O_all:
            Combined_datetime = datetime.combine(date, O_all).strftime('%y%m%d %H:%M')
            data.append([Combined_datetime,ID])
        else:
            data.append(['',ID])
    print(data)
```

You can explore more pythonic way of writing code. The above code seems very basic and sorry for that.

Comment: No luck. The error is again `TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not str`. This also does not work 'O_all=time.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M')', which gives `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: I hope `row[0]`, `row[6]` are of type `str`

Comment: Yes, they are from a csv file, so by default the csv.reader reads each object in a row as strings. Then it's converted into datetime objects. Everything runs fine, until I try to combine the 'date' & 'O_all' which are both in 'datetime.datetime' object format. The problem is, I don't know how to get 'datetime.time' in stead of 'datetime.datetime' object.

Comment: As per python3 [`datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine), first and second parameters are `date` and `time` respectively.

Comment: `datetime.strptime(row[6],'%H:%M').time()` does the work of producing `datetime.time` object. So, the updated code should work.